# Put N Unicode before variable in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We usually use `N` for unicode string literals like this:

```
Select * 
From Customer 
Where Name = N'កខគ' --Unicode
```

Now I want to change it to be like this:

```
Declare @a varchar(Max)

Select * 
From Customer 
Where Name = N''+@a
```

At the second SQL statement it doesn't work at all. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The `N` is only used as a prefix to coerce unicode *literals*.  If your `@a` variable is already one of the unicode types (e.g. `NVARCHAR`) then it's not necessary to convert or coerce it in any way.

Comment: I use this problem in Function(Table-valued Function) and i have a parameter @a,can be American Standard or Unicode, to use in where clause if i don't use N i am not available to select at all but only English letters